# Download a whole wordpress website with wget

Tags: wordpress, download, frontend, wget

I want to download all pages (with nested links) of a [website](https://motamem.org/) with `wget`. I tried the following command:

```sh
wget --reject php,xml --exclude-domains https://motamem.org/wp-content/plugins/ProProfile/ajax/upme-get-avatar.php?email=' + new_user_email,https://motamem.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php,https://wprp.sovrn.com/static/,https:\/\/motamem.org\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php,https://motamem.org/xmlrpc.php,https://motamem.org/feed/,https://motamem.org/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml,https://motamem.org/xmlrpc.php?rsd,https://motamem.org/wp-json/  -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.79 Safari/537.36" -mkEpnp -l10 -e robots=off --page-requisites --html-extension --adjust-extension  --convert-links https://motamem.org/
```

but with these problems:

1. I can't get all the pages, but only `index.html` of each directory.
2. I tried to add `-mkEpnp` options but links are not relative.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had luck downloading PHP (effectively Wordpress) websites with wget, but I have had luck with httrack e.g. on Ubuntu:

`sudo apt install httrack`
`httrack 'your website here'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

wget -r --mirror --page-requisites --convert-links --span-hosts -U mozilla -F  http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this command we can download easily all files from WordPress.

```
wget --mirror --page-requisites --convert-link --no-clobber --no-parent --domains yoursite.com https://yoursite.com/
```